# Is it possible to know the number of American residents/students/tourists leaving France each year?

Tags: data-request, usa, demographics, france

Regarding an implementation my company is conducting in France, I would like to know if it would be possible to know the number of American citizens leaving France each year?

Comment: As far as I know, there is no population register in France. The majority of their statistics are based on census data. It is unlikely that the data you are looking for is publicly available, if exists at all. I have checked Eurostat, OECD and Insee (national statistical agency of France). There are no such data in these three sources.

Comment: Do you consider people with both US and French passports as Americans?

Answer (score 2):

It seems likely that the vast majority are tourists, so you should be able to get a good first approximation by looking at tourist arrival numbers - generally speaking, tourist arrivals & departures in any given year should be about equal!

(Both the American and French governments publish statistics on tourism numbers.)

This will account for a [few million](http://articles.latimes.com/2014/jan/01/news/la-trb-britain-france-americans-favorite-destination-mexico-most-20131220) departures. By comparison, US students in France [number 10-20,000](http://articles.latimes.com/2014/jan/01/news/la-trb-britain-france-americans-favorite-destination-mexico-most-20131220), and there are [around 100,000 expatriates](http://france.usembassy.gov/us-france-americans.html). Even if they all travel once or twice a year, the tourist numbers will still dominate the estomate.

Answer (score 2):

Yes, you can get a general ball park figure, but it is based on a lot of assumptions. My main assumption is when you say leave, you mean as departing from France merely as a tourism function and not a permanent relocation.

- Assumption 1: The significant amount of travel by Americans will travel directly by air from France to the United States of America.

  - The Bureau of Transportation Statistics provides the number of passengers traveling to and from the United States of America, find the information [here](http://www.transtats.bts.gov/Fields.asp?Table_ID=261). If you take only the passengers traveling from France to the United States of America, you get a general idea of how many people travel the route; about 3,300,356 passengers in 2014.

    - A couple of caveats, the number of passengers is only for the direct routes, so trips that puddle jump to England and then travel to the United States are not counted.
    - Passengers on these trips are counted if they are coming from other countries as part of a puddle jump, the passenger could be flying from Dubai to visit the United States.
- Assumption 2: If we eliminate French tourists, all that remains is American travelers; disregarding spoke operations.

  - The Office of Travel Tourism and [Industries provides International Visitation in the United States](http://travel.trade.gov/outreachpages/inbound.general_information.inbound_overview.html). It specifically develops a [French tourism synopsis](http://travel.trade.gov/outreachpages/download_data_table/2014_France_Market_Profile.pdf), among other nations, to which an estimated 1,625,000 French tourists visit the states. Leaving us with 1,675,356 passengers with flights to in the United States of America.
- Assumption 3: United States tourists do not all directly fly to France and they will leave France within the year they arrive.

  - Checking the [outbound United States tourists](http://travel.trade.gov/outreachpages/download_data_table/2014_US_Travel_Abroad.pdf), 2,124,000.
- Assumption 4: Expatriate travel is insignificant.

  - The [United States Embassy estimates](http://france.usembassy.gov/us-france-americans.html) there are 100,000 expats in France. Which assuming a 10% travel inclination to leave France, does not have a significant impact on estimates. This piggy backs on Andrew's comment.

Based on all of this, you can crudely estimate on a yearly basis the number of Americans traveling from France. For 2014 you can estimate between 1.6 million to 2.1 million Americans traveling from France to the United States. The great thing about the BTS data is that it is available on a monthly basis.